# List text in 3 columns

Tags: list, multiple-columns

I have been stuck like 3 hours without finding anything on the net.

this is what I want to achieve: https://gyazo.com/281aa4fd3ddc3824063899da5f121d72

this is what I get:
https://gyazo.com/d50617fa8a6ff38d36b9b0c795328b89

Can't make the first list unable to invade column 2, that's my problem.

I've tried to use div, tables, some columns atributes, but it seems I can't make it work.

So just simple as that… I need 3 columns, 1 for list, that's all.

```css
#fondo{
 align-content: center;
 width: 960px;
}

#cabecera{
 background-color: grey; 
}

#cabecera H1{
 align-content: center;
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
}

#datos {
 width: 260px;
 float: left;
}

#contenido {
 width: 700px;
 float: right;
}

#columnas{
 width: 700px;
 column-count: 3;
 /*-webkit-column-break-break-inside: avoid;
 -webkit-column-break-break-after: always;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>HTML &amp; CSS: Curso práctico avanzado</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fondo">

  <div id="cabecera">
   <h1>HTML &amp; CSS: Curso práctico avanzado</h1>   
  </div>
  <div>
   <div id="datos">
    <h2>Datos del libro</h2>
    <ul>
     <li>Título: HTML &amp; CSS: Curso práctico avanzado</li>
     <li>Autor: Sergio Luján Mora</li>
     <li>Editorial: Publicaciones Altaria</li>
     <li>Año de publicación: 2015</li>
     <li>ISBN: 978-84-944049-4-8</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="contenido">
    <div>
     <h2>Descripción del libro</h2>
     <p>
      Aunque los inicios de Internet se remontan a los años sesenta,
      no ha sido hasta los años noventa cuando, gracias a la Web, se ha
      extendido su uso por todo el mundo. En pocos años, la Web ha
      evolucionado enormemente: se ha pasado de páginas sencillas, con
      pocas imágenes y contenidos estáticos que eran visitadas por unos
      pocos usuarios a páginas complejas, con contenidos dinámicos que
      provienen de bases de datos y que son visitadas por miles de
      usuarios al mismo tiempo.
     </p>
     <p>
      Todas las páginas están internamente construidas con la misma
      tecnología, con el Lenguaje de marcas de hipertexto (Hypertext
      Markup Language, HTML) y con las Hojas de estilo en cascada
      (Cascading Style Sheets, CSS).
     </p>
     <p>
      Este libro es adecuado para cualquiera que tenga interés en
      aprender a desarrollar sus propias páginas web. No son necesarios
      conocimientos previos para aprender con este libro, lo único que
      es necesario es saber utilizar un ordenador y saber navegar por la
      Web.
     </p> 
     <h2>Contenido del libro</h2>
     <p>
      El contenido de este libro se estructura en tres apartados bien
      diferenciados:
     </p>    
    </div>
    <div id="columnas">
     <div style="width: 233px">
      <ul>
       <li>En la primera parte del libro se trabajan conceptos generales
       que son necesarios para poder desarrollar páginas web; se explican
       conceptos de estructura física y estructura lógica (o estructura
       de navegación) de un sitio web. Se detalla cómo influye la
       estructura física en las URL o direcciones que se emplean a la
       hora de crear los enlaces de un sitio web. Pasando por el concepto
       de "estándar web", un término general que se emplea para
       refererirse a los estándares que define su funcionamiento como
       HTML y CSS, empleados para el desarrollo de las páginas web en el
       lado del cliente.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 233px">
      <ul>
       <li>En la segunda parte se trabaja HTML. Partiendo de la estructura básica de una página web, se explican las etiquetas de
       HTML que se utilizan para definir el texto, los enlaces, las
       listas, las tablas, los formularios y los elementos
       multimedia.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 233px">
      <ul>
       <li>En la tercera y última parte se explica CSS, el lenguaje que
       se emplea para definir el formato y la presentación de una página
       web. Se explica cómo utilizar el color, cómo definir la
       presentación del texto, de las tablas y de los formularios; cómo
       realizar transformaciones y transiciones con el fin de diseñar una
       página web.</li>       
      </ul>
     </div>     
    </div>    
   </div>   
  </div>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to embed screenshots and code into your question. This way the question will continue to be relevant and make sense even if the links you have posted stop working. You can read this SO introduction to embedding runnable code in your question - https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code with the complete HTML and CSS in case it's causing the issue. Don't use screenshots of your code, instead copy the text into your question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference